# Flask - Creating dynamic URL based on user input

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a dynamic URL based on user's input from an HTML form.

For example, if a user types in 'AAPL' or 'KO', the next page should be:
*webapp.com/result/AAPL* or *webapp.com/result/KO*

index.html:

```
<div class="cell" id="cell-1-2">
  <span class="data" style="text-align: center;">
      <form action="{{ url_for('ticker_result', variable='variable') }}" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="variable" placeholder="search ticker or company" maxlength="4" 
             font-size="24px" style="text-transform:uppercase">
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="tickerSymbol();">
    </form>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've tried renaming the 'variable' part to several different things and nothing works so I'm just stuck at this point.

main.py:

```
# Routing to the homepage
@app.route("/")
def markert_hours_today():
    return render_template(
        "index.html")

# Routing to the result page
@app.route("/result/<variable>", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def ticker_result(variable):
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = request.form["variable"]
        return render_template(
            "result.html", 
            result=result)
```

When I run the local environment, and type in a ticker symbol, the next URL is:
*webapp.com/result/variable*

I'm assuming it's HTML that I need to edit? I've read the quickstart documentation for Flask which isn't making sense to me and looked up similar questions but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are coming at it from the wrong way. When Jinja creates index.html based on your template you can't know what `variable` is going to be, so how is Jinja supposed to know?

What you need to do is send the form back to the same route and then redirect the user to whatever they typed in. So something like this:

```
from flask import request, redirect, url_for

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def markert_hours_today():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['variable']
        return redirect(url_for('ticker_result', variable=result)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Edit: forgot to rename variable from user_input to result.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do I need to edit my HTML at all?

Comment: Remove the action attribute, the form will get posted to the same page.

Comment: Okay, this is what I have: `<form action="#" method="POST">` and it's saying method not allowed for the requested URL when I click to go to the results page.

Comment: Did you change the accepted methods for the "/" route? Also see my comment above, try removing the action attribute altogether. Apparently that isn't needed when posting to the same page.

Comment: Thank you for that. Now just need to figure out what to put for user_input as it's not defined. Thanks again!

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change `user_input` to `result`, see updated version.